# 301 redirect all subfolders in subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My site has a subdomain: docs.example.com and many folders within: docs.example.com/math, docs.example.com/science, docs.example.com/language and so on. All these URLs are indexed in Google. I need the subdomain and its subfolders to be redirected to the main URL: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

I need to do a 301 redirect because of SEO. I have access to .htaccess in the host server. I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^docs.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Works fine for docs.example.com but for docs.example.com/math I get a 404 error. Everything beneath docs.example.com MUST be 301 redirected, all subfolders and files.

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 3):

Please following htaccess rules at top of your .htaccess Rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?docs\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

***Additional notes:*** With rules following are suggestions/improvements.

- Additionally make sure you place your htaccess file at root level.
- Use NC flag with host checking condition.
- Use NE flag while redirecting.
- Make sure your sub-domains are created by vhosts file.

Comment: @Donald Torres, could you please do let me know if this solution has worked for you? Thank you.